# Unable to Install nvidia-settings

Tags: nvidia

I am trying to install nvidia-settings on Ubuntu 12.04. This is a fresh install done today (Jan 25, 2014). I have nvidia-331 installed (I believe it's 331.38, but don't think the exact version matters here).

```
johngu@Guru-Laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-settings : Depends: screen-resolution-extra (>= 0.14ubuntu2.1) but 0.14ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


johngu@Guru-Laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install screen-resolution-extra
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
screen-resolution-extra is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Any help here would be appreciated. I just want to have access to the nvidia control panel.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install`.If any error occurs then post its o/p.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `sudo apt-get install -f` but that didn't work.

I ended up downloading the `.deb` file from here:

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/screen-resolution-extra/

and installing manually with `sudo dpkg -i`  After that, the dependency was resolved and I could install nvidia-settings.